# How to configure cron jobs for cakephp site on an Amazon AWS (bitnami stack)?

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, cron, bitnami

I want to execute a shell script in every minute.
I used this command

```
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sitename/app && Console/cake Sendnotification
```

Where `Sendnotification` is the shell name and `sitename` site folder name.

Please let me know. I have been trying to fix this since from last 10 hours.

Comment: You may have better chances to receive an answer if you'd explain the actual problem you are experiencing, ie does the job run at all, do you receive any errors, etc...

Comment: Thanks for reply.No I didn't get any errors.I created a shell and Task.When I execute the shell task through putty(SSH),then its working but when I set the cron to execute the same shell then its not working. Here is my code:
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sitename/app && Console/cake Sendnotification
In the same way I have done before in other dedicatated servers,but dont know why its not working in bitnami instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because PHP installed in non-standard path. You will need to edit the `Console/cake` bake shell script to include the path to PHP executable.

Since you are using **Bitnami**, you can add the following line to the shell script:

```
export PATH=/opt/bitnami/php/bin:$PATH
```

So your Console/cake file should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=/opt/bitnami/php/bin:$PATH

################################################################################
#
# Bake is a shell script for running CakePHP bake script
#
# CakePHP(tm) :  Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
# Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)

...
```

(This works for me on CakePHP 2.x)

**Bonus**: You can edit your cron task to log the console output to a file for debugging:

```
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sitename/app && Console/cake Sendnotification  > /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/sitename/logs/Sendnotification_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`-cron.log 2>&1
```